# I have configured my FB Conversion API with FB PArtner option ( Available in FB event manager section) my variable saying undefined

Tags: google-tag-manager, date-conversion

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYQyD.png)

it supposed to return the value like product name, currency and value. but it is returning undefined. the total process is done by fb-eventmanager-partner inegration system. which is actually a no code option to install the conversion api in meta event manager. if any one here has used that option please hlep me mentioning the next step after setting up the process. Do i need to  create any event in web container or the FB will do it by js code. coz i am getting data in pixel helper and test event also say getting data from browser but i configured it for server side...